# How can I add lm_paypal subscriptions to registration page?

Tags: drupal, paypal, drupal-7

I've recently installed the lm_paypal module to my drupal site, and I've created two different subscriptions. When users subscribe and pay, they are granted a user account (a specific Role that has access to various pages).

How can I add my subscriptions to the user registration form?

**The goal:** After users fill out the registration form, I want them to be taken to the paypal page for payment (e.g. Continue to Checkout).

Answer (score 0):

this is a great question, I'm going to try to work on something like this and let you know!

In the mean time, check this link out, it has some ideas.
https://drupal.org/node/125816